# Changing functions based on checkbox being checked or not

Tags: jquery

I have the same function checking 2 different text input fields in a form.  If a checkbox is checked, I need the function to run on one of the text input fields.  If the checkbox is not checked, I need the function to run on the other text input field.

Here is the checkbox:

```
<input id="use_different_addresses" type="checkbox" value="1" name="use_different_addresses" />Use different address<br />
```

By default the checkbox is not checked.  When unchecked, I need this function to run:

```
$('#customer_country_name').change(function() {
    if ($('#customer_country_name').val() != 'United States') {
        $('.radio_us').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.radio_us').show();
    }
});
```

When the checkbox is checked, I need this function to run:

```
$('#shipping_country_name').change(function() {
    if ($('#customer_country_name').val() != 'United States') {
        $('.radio_us').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.radio_us').show();
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4UkTP/

It's probably not the prettiest jQuery (I'll admit I'm a newbie), but it works! :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add a check to the top of each method to determine if it should run or not based on the `checked` state

```
$('#customer_country_name').change(function() {
  if (!$('#use_different_addresses').is(':checked')) {
   ...
  }
}

$('#shipping_country_name').change(function() {
  if ($('#use_different_addresses').is(':checked')) {
   ...
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

OP clarified in comments that they wanted certain radio boxes to be hidden when the check-box was checked.  Here's the solution I recomended

```
$('#use_different_addresses').change(function() {
  if ($('#use_different_addresses').is(':checked')) {
    $('.radio_us').hide();
  } else {
    $('.radio_us').show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey JaredPar, thanks for the input.  I get the concept of what you're saying but for some reason my attempt to integrate this didn't work.  I've put the code of what I did here: http://jsfiddle.net/flinx777/c2PCT/ ... is it obvious what I did wrong?

Comment: @flinx777 what behavior are you expecting in that app?

Comment: The behavior I'm looking for is when someone changes the value of their country in the input text box, if it is not the United States, it will hide the labels that have class of "radio_us".  The challenge is that I have 2 input text fields where users can enter their country.  If the checkbox with id of "use_different_addresses" is not checked, then my function should run on the input with the id of "customer_country_name", but if the checkbox is checked, then I need to run my function on the input field with id of "shipping_country_name".  Hope that helps clarify.

Comment: thnx again for the help.  It still is missing the selection of which input field the function is to be run on based on the checkbox status.  My goal is if the checkbox is unchecked, we'll check the value of the country in the input field with id of "customer_country_name".  If the checkbox is checked, the input field with id of "shipping_country_name", we'll check the value and run the function accordingly.  I hope I'm making sense.  Sorry if I'm not being very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more markup, you can use `.toggle()` to trigger the `.change()`

```
$("#use_different_addresses").toggle(function(){
  $('#customer_country_name').change();
}, function(){
  $('#shipping_country_name').change();
});
```